# Как сделать так чтобы авторизованная страница оставалась?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Все делает нормально авторизацию, то есть неавторизованнцю страницу не показывает авторизованному пользователю, типо автоирзация, регистрация и так далее, а неавторизованному пользователю не показывает. У меня проблема в том, что если перейти на страницу авторизации через url, то будет переход или перезагрузить страницу, то соответственно из хранилище данные стерутся, 
То как писать код страницы для проверок?
Я допустим написал так
**src/store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    accessToken: '',
  },
  mutations: {
    addToken(state, value){
      state.accessToken = value;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addToken(context, token){
      context.commit('addToken', token);
      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    }
  },
  getters: {
    user: state => {
      return state.accessToken !== '';//Была идея сюда localStorage добавить, но там выходило что первый раз не происходит редирект, а вот после перезагрузки на страницу "/home" перейдет
    }
  }
})
```

**src/router.js**

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login,
        meta: {
            requireAuth: false,
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/home',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home,
        meta: {
            requireAuth: true
        }
    }
  ]
});
```

**main.js**

```
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requireAuth) && !store.getters.user) {
        next({
            name: 'login',
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: я с vue.js не знаком, но вся идея авторизации обычно связана с Сессиями,  ну либо конечно куками. Но чаще с сессиями. Куки имеют время жизни, а сессия сохраняется до logout. Я могу помочь только таким советом, так что, извиняюсь, что не могу написать пример кода.

Comment: Там для варианта авторизации с сессиями как понимаю, у меня проиходит авторизация через oauth2, это через токен